# Quitar publicidad en una WebView Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, webview, webview-android, popup

cuando el usuario esta en la webview tiene que entrar a otra pagina dentro de la webview pero en esta interacción sale publicidad me gustaría poder bloquear eso, talvez alguna forma de eliminar ventanas emergentes ya que según yo esas son las publicidades que salen, este es mi código probé algunas cosas pero sin el resultado deseado, gracias de antemano.

```
String url = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    private WebView miVisorWeb;
    private String mCurrentUrl;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pagina1);

         miVisorWeb =  this.findViewById(R.id.visorWeb);//CustomWebView ?

        WebSettings webView_settings = miVisorWeb.getSettings();

        webView_settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                setTitle(view.getTitle());
                //do your stuff ...
            }
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (!url.contains(url)){ view.loadUrl(url); }

                return false;
            }
        };

        miVisorWeb.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
        miVisorWeb.clearCache(true);
        miVisorWeb.clearHistory();
        webView_settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);//XSS vulnerable set to false ?
        webView_settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);//set to false ?
        miVisorWeb.loadUrl("https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");//load something
        miVisorWeb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        miVisorWeb.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

        WebChromeClient webChromeClient = new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
                result.cancel();
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onJsConfirm(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
                result.cancel();
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onJsPrompt(WebView view, String url, String message, String defaultValue, JsPromptResult result) {
                result.cancel();
                return true;
            }
        };
    }
    @Override public void onBackPressed() { if (miVisorWeb.isFocused() && miVisorWeb.canGoBack()) { miVisorWeb.goBack(); } else { super.onBackPressed(); finish(); } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La publicidad se carga dentro de la página web que cargas dentro mediante :

```
 miVisorWeb.loadUrl("https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
```

**en este debería ser la página donde deberías modificar para evitar se cargue la publicidad.**

Una opción es deshabilitar la ejecución de JavaScript, aunque esto podría afectar el funcionamiento de la página si es que usas JavaScript para alguna funcionalidad:

```
 webView_settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
```